# Clear the combo box value

Tags: extjs

I have a problem in my application related to combo box, actually I am using a combo box in multiple views, if it is loaded once , the loaded value are existing for all the views , I want that the value must be persist for the loaded view after changing the view the value must be reset for the changed view.

It is the code of my combo which I have used:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    emptyText: 'Select',
    fieldLabel: 'Company Name',
    labelSeparator: '',
    name: 'CompanyID',
    displayField: 'CompanyName',
    valueField: 'companyId',
    queryMode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    bind: {
        store: '{companystore}',
        value: '{CompanyID}'
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changing the view"? Do you work with a tabpanel component?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding the problem correctly, but you can try and reset the combobox before rendering it. You can also do the same thing but reseting it when loading the view where the combobox is used.

```
listeners:{
   beforerender: function(combobox){
       combobox.reset();
   }
}
```

You can also try setting the value to an empty value before rendering the combobox.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html